# Question about the length of module

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm reading the Stack's project, Lemma 10.52.4

[image]

Why $1 - gf_2$ is unit in $R$?

My first attempt is, by the Nakayama lemma (If $IM = M$, $M$ is finite, and $I \subseteq \operatorname{rad(R)} = \mathfrak{m}$, then $M = 0$), if we find a finite $R$-module $M \neq 0$ such that $IM = M ( I := <1-gf_2> )$, then $I \nsubseteq \operatorname{rad(R)} = \mathfrak{m}$ and   $1-gf_2$ is unit in $R$.

But how can we find such $M$? $Rf_1x$? or.. $Rf_1f_2x$? Part that makes me stuck is the statement
$M \subseteq IM$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_2 \in \mathfrak{m}$, so $gf_2 \in \mathfrak{m}$, so $1-gf_2 \notin \mathfrak{m}$. Since $R$ is a local ring, the set of units in $R$ is precisely $R \setminus \mathfrak{m}$. Thus, $1-gf_2$ is a unit in $R$.

Comment: Wow, very simple approach. Thank you.